# Lightbox not displaying content correctly Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

I am building a wordpress portfolio with custom post types. The page shows thumbnails of the images and when you roll over them you see the title, the excerpt and a link to see the content of the post in a lightbox. To get the lightbox I am using a plugin called Lightbox Plus ColorBox. For some reason only some of the images work correctly with the lightbox and on other ones it displays nothing and you can't close it. I assume it is getting stuck in a loop somehow but I'm really not sure how to fix it.

The website URL is http://www.ginahughes.co.uk/commercial-photography/

This is my page code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
  //list terms in a given taxonomy (useful as a widget for twentyten)
    $taxonomy = 'commercial-project-name';
    $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<div class="project-titles wrap">
    <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
        echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="inner-content" class="wrap clearfix">
                    <div id="main" class="clearfix" role="main">
                        <div id="portfolio">   

                            <div class="group"> 
                                  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
                                      <?php 
                                  query_posts('post_type=commercial-photo&posts_per_page=100');
                                  $i=1;
                                  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

                                  <?php  
                                      $title= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_title()));  
                                      $desc= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_content())); 
                               ?>     


                                        <div class="bp-wrapper">  
                                        <a title="<?=$title?>: <?=$desc?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-thumb'); ?></a>

                                        <div class="bp-post-details">
                                            <a title="<?=$title?>: <?=$desc?>" rel="lightbox" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                            <h4><a class="lbp-inline-link-<?=$i?> cboxElement" href="#">
                                                 <?=$title?></a></strong></h4>
                                            <p><?php print get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>

                                        </div> 

                                        <div style="display: none;">
                                                <div id="lbp-inline-href-<?=$i?>" style="padding:10px; ">
                                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                           </div>
                                            </div> 

                                            <?php $i++;endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                    </div> <?php // end #main ?>
            </div> <?php // end #inner-content ?>

        </div> <?php // end #content ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems one of which is that you have block elements -`<h4>` inside inline elements- `<a>` but I think the main problem is the following in your scripts.js :

```
$( "#zoomIn" ).click(function() {
$( "#zoomingOverlay" ).show( "slow" );
});
$( "#close" ).click(function() {
$( "#zoomingOverlay" ).hide( "slow" );
});
```

Wordpress uses no-conflict JQuery which means that in order to use the $ you need to place it in a no-conflict wrapper. Like so :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
    // and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut
});
```

To read more about this see [jQuery noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I had forgotten about that piece of code, it actually has nothing to do with the zooming gallery so I have deleted it. This doesn't seem to have solved the problem though. What's strange is that it works on some thumbnails but not others. . .

Comment: Yes, but it isn't always getting the correct image (at least not for the zooming). I think the problem probably has to do with `$this` not targeting the correct element.

Comment: I agree it seems to be struggling to target the right element but I really have no idea how to force it to target the correct post.